# The meaning of "He ripped out a fathom and a half o' brimstone Spanish,"

Tags: meaning

> '"Why, Sim!" he says. Just like that--after twenty year! "Sim," he
>   says, "what brings you?" '"Pudden," I says, not knowing whether to
>   laugh or cry. '"You told me to bring cannon-shot next time, an' I've
>   brought 'em." 'He saw we had. **He ripped out a fathom and a half o'
>   brimstone Spanish,** and he swung down on our rail, and he kissed me
>   before all his fine young captains. His men was swarming out of the
>   lower ports ready to unload us. When he saw how I'd considered all his
>   likely wants, he kissed me again.

This is from "Simple Simon" by Radyard Kipling. I don't understand the meaning of the sentence below, even when I have read the note of the Kipling Society.

He ripped out a fathom and a half o' brimstone Spanish,

[the whole text](https://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/RewardsFaries/simplesimon.html)

*The note of Kipling Society
[Page 300, line 4] brimstone Spanish Brimstone is sulphur. In this context, 'fiery', or 'burning'. The reader can assume that Drake was swearing exuberantly in Spanish.

I am glad if somebody would kindly teach me.

meaning

Comment: The Kipling society note gives a pretty good explanation of what it means. What are you unsure about? This definition of **rip out** seems to agree with their explanation: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/rip+out

Comment: A fathom is a nautical measure of the depth of water (6 feet or 1.8 metres).  The implication is that Drake uttered a long string of oaths.

Comment: Kipling's first name is Rudyard, not Radyard

Comment: @MikeBrockington I don't know about that, I think he was pretty rad XD.

Comment: Thank you so much that I now understand what the note of Kipling Society means.